# MvvmCross ApiExamples iOS UIDatePicker Date Off By One Day

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Screenshot from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples DateTime Example.

Although both dates match, the picker does not.  I've tried both setting the timezone on the picker and trying to implement a value converter without success.

```
public class DateConverter : MvxValueConverter<NSDate, DateTime>
{
    protected override DateTime Convert(NSDate date, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(date.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);
    }
    protected override NSDate ConvertBack(DateTime date, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate((date - (new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))).TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug - sadly "works ok on my machine" :/ Maybe try copying the mvx datepicker code over into a mydatepicker to see if you can get some extra help from the debugger

Comment: I'm thinking this is a time zone issue...my location is -6 hours UTC that could be affecting it, but haven't pinned that down yet.  I'm not even sure if this is a mvvmcross issue or just would happen in iOS regardless.  I'll try the above and see if playing with my computer's timezone also affects the output.  I should add the Android DatePicker example works fine.

Comment: It is a timezone issue, I set my computer timezone to UTC and the example works as expected.  For addressing this in MvvmCross would you recommend a Value Converter or another path?  Setting datePicker.TimeZone = NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone; has no effect.

Comment: If this is a phone issue as well as sim, then I'd suggest this needs fixing in the source

Comment: Happens on device and phone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this, issue is UIDatePicker does not respect setting `TimeZone` or `Locale`, hence everything returned or set to it is expected to be in UTC.

MvvmCross was patched to take this into account

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/662